# PHP uploaded file name doesnt show up in browser

Tags: php, file

All of my other form data is visible, but the name of the file is not showing up in the browser.

Here is a little portion of my code:

```
<form  method="POST" action=<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>  entype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="file" value="yoyo">
</form>

<?php
    echo $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    echo "problem";
?>
```

and this is the output:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xamp\htdocs\colgWeb\index.php on line 228
>   problem

Comment: Try to `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES,true).'</pre>';` and show result here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/): You misspelled `enctype` (it has a `c` in it).

Consequently, the form is being submitted with the default (url based) encoding which doesn't support file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think that as a two step page. First, you send your form, then you use the input.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="file" value="yoyo">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_FILES["file"]))
    {
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        echo "File: $name";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The echo has plenty to do there, it echos the value that was just assigned to `$name`. The OP said "All of my other form data is visible", so its *very* unlikely that the problem is that they just forgot to click the submit button.

Comment: You should test the code in your answer. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Quentin From the infos and the code I have, I think it might be the problem.

Comment: Hmm, as well as not fixing the problem, you've introduced a new one: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Users/david/tmp/jkflsdjkfl/index.php on line 8`

Comment: It isn't the problem. You can test it and see that it isn't.

Comment: Your latest edit has fixed the syntax error you introduced. It still doesn't work though. `$_FILES["file"]` is never set.

Comment: Congratulations. You appear to have read my answer and fixed your code… so now it reads like a game of spot-the-difference where you have changed 4 things, only one of which is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. You are using same name (ie "file") for both file and submit button."

```
<form  method="POST" action=<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>  entype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="yoyo">
</form>

<?php
    echo $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    echo "problem";
?>
```